# handling google map markers in qTip2

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, qtip2

I'm trying to create an internal admin interface to quickly add locations to events using qTip and google maps. Here's a simplified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mykel_suthertun/RWtRe/

It currently works, minus two bugs:

1. Markers are duplicated every time the qTip is opened. *(Solved. See comment below.)*
2. It can't currently handle opening a map with no map center or marker defined.

**Re: #1** - To see what I mean, click the pin icon on the right. Click off. Click to open it again. There are two markers in the same spot now. It should only create it once.

I assume this is because I have the marker being created in the qTip's "show" event and not in "render". When I moved it to "render" I ran into errors getting the map to display at all.

**Re: #2** - To see this bug, just click any of the target icons. I just need it to open a default map state if no marker or center is defined. How would I adjust my code to handle this?

Comment: **Re: #1** - Solved. I wanted to handle this by moving the marker code from the 'show' event to the 'render' event so that it would only execute once. Couldn't get that to work. I figured out a way around it though. I created a global var for marker as null, then checked to see if it exists in the show event. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mykel_suthertun/RWtRe/35/)

Comment: Nevermind. I eventually _did_ get it to work in the render event, which was a big step in the right direction to fixing issue #2 and a few others I was having. I'm very close to getting the whole thing working and I'll post the fiddle when I'm done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Final fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/mykel_suthertun/RWtRe/36/)**

There's some terribly inefficient JavaScript in there (duplicated functions, etc), but it currently runs and does everything I needed it to. I added a couple other features in there since the original as well. Hope this helps someone out.